# C++ Add constraints to a noexcept member function of template class

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, requires-clause

I have a 3D vector template class and I want to add a normalize member function to it.

Normalizing a vector only makes sense, if they use floating point numbers.

I want to use the c++20 `requires` syntax with the `std::floating_point` concept.

```
template<typename Type>
class vector3 {

  [...]

  vector3& normalize() requires std::floating_point<Type> noexcept;

}
```

But the compiler (gcc 11.2.0) gives me an error

```
error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
  242 |   vector3& normalize() requires (std::floating_point<Type>) noexcept;
      |                                                          ^
      |                                                          ;
```

Comment: `normalize` is not a template. Afaik this prevents you from using a concept here. (It certainly does prevent sfinae. You could introduce a specialization here, but personally I'd create 2 seperate templates with different names and introduce an alias template named `vector3`: `template<class T> using vector3 = std::conditional_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, floating_point_vector3<T>, integer_vector3<T>>;`

Comment: Should be `vector3 & normalize() noexcept requires std::is_floating_point_v<Type>;`

Comment: @fabian - You can add a constraint to a member of a template. The pre-c++20 hack you propose is meant to be replaced.

Comment: @Osyotr You are right, the ordering actually matter. Maybe write an answer so I can mark it

Comment: I agree. The comment from @Osyotr *could* be made into an answer ... but an explanation of why the `noexcept` needs to precede the `requires` clause would be required (*ugh*), I think. That's the tricky part. ;)

Comment: @AdrianMole - It's not tricky, it's just the grammar. Just like the words I just wrote and you now read must come in a certain order to make a meaningful sentence.

Comment: @StoryTeller  Yes, grammar it is. And tricky that is, too.

Comment: @AdrianMole - no, not really. Not every typo is worth a thesis.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I suspect a lot of people are going to have the same typo, so having an answer is worthwhile.

Comment: @NicolBolas - It's only worthwhile if the question comes up easily in a search (more easily than just pointing out the typo). I have my doubts here.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: You seem to agree that the problem is one that people are likely to encounter, so your only issue seems to be one of phrasing. If you think there's a more search-engine-friendly way to phrase the question, feel free to edit the title. Or ask your own version and mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I did not pass any judgement on the problem, though if you press, then no I do not agree. I merely pointed out the premise for when a duplicate is "worthwhile".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`noexcept` is part of `declarator`, and `requires-clause` must come after `declarator` ([dcl.decl](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.decl))

so you need to write

```
// from @Osyotr in comment
vector3 & normalize() noexcept requires std::is_floating_point_v<Type>;
```

---